# A function with a finite limit at (both) 0 and infinity

Tags: calculus, examples-counterexamples

I ask myself if there exists a $f(x)$ function that limit goes to a finite number for both when x goes to 0 and to infinity. Is it possible in some way ?

Comment: Constants, $\frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}$, ...

Comment: Let $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer is not there a simple function ? I guess $\frac{1}{1-x}$ ?

Comment: @optimalcontrol: That is not defined at $x=1$. Take Daniel's example, say $x\mapsto {1 \over 1+x^2}$.

Comment: I'd consider constants the simplest of all functions. Lots of things work. Your example works too (but, just to let it not be unmentioned, it has a pole at $1$).

Answer (score 4):

How about the constant function $f(x)=1$? 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1\qquad \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Not only do such functions exist, there are a whole lot of them!

- Constant functions, $f(x) = C$, satisfy your condition
- Continuous functions with limits at infinity satisfy your condition, i.e. $e^{-x^2}$, or $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ or $\arctan(x)$.
- Let's take a $\delta > 0$ and $M>\delta>0$. Then, take any continuous funtion $f:[0, \delta)$ a function $g:(M, \infty)\to \mathbb R$ for which the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$$ exists, and one arbitrary function $h:[\delta, M]$. Then the function 
  $$F(x)\begin{cases}
  f(x) & x < \delta\\
  h(x) & \delta\leq x\leq M\\
  g(x) & M<x 
  \end{cases}$$
  has a limit as $x$ approaches $0$ and $\infty$.